# Scheduled Annotation not working without component scan

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I am using Spring's task executor to schedule a method at regular interval.

```
public class ABC{
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=100000)
    public void test(){
    }
}
```

It doesn't work with simple bean declaration for the class ABC.

```
<bean id="abc" class="com.test.ABC" />
```

If I put component scan then it works fine.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
```

What could be the reason?

I think, both should work fine as Component scan is just an alternative for defining individual bean. might be something wrong from my side.

Let me know if my thoughts are not correct.

Thanks,